# Getting Error in Production Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

[image]

I am stuck on this little problem, hoping that you can help me, I followed all the asset compiling steps from the docs. The app is working totally fine on the local environment as soon as I deployed it causing the /livewire/livewire.js not found.

Comment: run `composer install` in live

Comment: Bro, it's not a composer error

Comment: livewire is installed by composer so if your not getting `livewire` asset you should install that  or directly import via https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/master/dist/livewire.js

Comment: My Hosting provider didn't give me ssh access, Anyhow Thanks